# Optimizing parameter in odeint with the output of a neural network in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to optimize the coefficients of an ODE using tensorflow.

```
def odeModel(state, t):
    x, y, z = tf.unstack(state)
    dx = y
    # Here I want to define dy and dz as follows:
    # [dy, dz] = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul([y, z], W) + b)
    return tf.stack([dx, dy, dz])
```

Basically, I aim to define [dy, dz] as a map from [y, z] that depends on appropriately sized TensorFlow variables 'W' and 'b'. Then, I would like to find 'W' and 'b' that minimizes a loss function that depends on the trajectory starting from 'state0'. Is that possible?

I aim to write the rest of the code along the following lines.

```
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
state0 = #Appropriate starting point, e.g., tf.constant([0, 1, 3], dtype=tf.float64)
states = tf.contrib.integrate.odeint(odeModel, state0, t)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(states[:, 2], 2))
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)
```

Of course, I need to the create a session and run the optimizer. The details are omitted for brevity. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve what I am shooting for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in exactly the way your describe:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


RS = np.random.RandomState(42)

# Defining model parameters as TF variables
W1 = tf.Variable(RS.randn(2, 1))
b1 = tf.Variable(RS.randn(1,))

W2 = tf.Variable(RS.randn(2, 1))
b2 = tf.Variable(RS.randn(1,))

def odeModel(state, t):
    x, y, z = tf.unstack(state)
    dx = y

    # Model definition
    dy = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims([y, z], -1), W1, transpose_a=True) + b1)
    dz = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims([y, z], -1), W2, transpose_a=True) + b2)
    return tf.stack([dx, tf.squeeze(dy), tf.squeeze(dz)])

t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
state0 = tf.constant([0, 1, 3], dtype=tf.float64)
states, info = tf.contrib.integrate.odeint(odeModel, state0, t, full_output=True)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(states[:, 2], 2))
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

# ----
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Value before optimizing
sess.run(W1)
# array  [[ 0.49671415],
#         [-0.1382643 ]]

# Optimize for 10 steps.
for i in range(10): sess.run(optimizer)

# Value after optimization
sess.run(W1)
# array([[ 0.38043613],
#        [-0.26166077]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is precisely what I needed. A quick comment: 'epoch' should be replaced with 'range'.